# Output result of queries to dataset in Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am running a number of spatial queries on a dataset in model builder and want the number of selected features to be saved in a table. I don't want the features themselves but just the number of features that the query found. Is this possible?

[image]

I want

ID| Site       |   Number

1 | Brisbane   | 9789

2 | Towoomba   | 8389

etc...

Comment: Perhaps a summary statistics with *count* of OID/FID. The options in model builder are somewhat limited. There is a get count tool but that's used for branching and the output of such I don't think can be logged.

Comment: Thanks, just thinking about it further, I will look at using http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/39155-Get-Count-Tool-with-Iterators-in-Model-Builder and maybe outputting to a collect values tool.

Comment: Summary Statistics as suggested by @MichaelMiles-Stimson is how I would do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone...

In the end it was quicker just to write a small script to get this with the Get Count Tool.

The script is

```
import arcpy
id=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fieldName=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
RowCount=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
logFile=r'D:\scratch\GetCountTool_output.txt'
log = open (logFile, 'a')
log.write(id+"|"+fieldName+"|"+RowCount)
log.close
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the [summary statistics tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000) will only get you half way there, it will give you one table per selection with the count of unique FID/OID. Geoprocessing tools honor selection layers and will only sum the selected features.

To compile the tables into a single table it is necessary to, for each sum table, [add a Site field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000047000000) and [calculate the name](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004m000000). Then the tables can be [merged](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000055000000) and [exported to text format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000n4000000) in the model. This will not do *pipe delimited*, to achieve this it is necessary to open the csv file and find & replace "," with "|".

As stated in the comment, there is a [Get Count tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n7000000) for modelbuilder but this is for condition branching and I don't know a way to get the output of this into a file using just modelbuilder. In python it wouldn't be a problem, the count could be written to a text file in pipe delim format using file operations!