# Select by Attributes iteration in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, iteration

Trying to

1. select all points by location  that fall within a polygon
2. select by attribute from the selected by location using an expression. so far it works fine  ..
3. I have a list of values -  I need to change the expression  every time the model run  and write the results to Excel or Text File  as table  as follows.

   ```
   call_type    -   Count
   ```

I know that can be accomplished using the iteration  but I couldn't figure it out.
[image]

Comment: I updated the model..  Only need to export the get count to text File

Comment: You can't write the count unless you use a bit of python. An alternative way that may work and keeps it entirely within model builder is after your selections you update a field with the value, then run a summary table tool after the model has run?

Comment: Thanks,  how can I update the field...  do you have any python snipped to accomplish the task.  Regards

Comment: this thread http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97930/output-result-of-queries-to-dataset-in-model-builder?answertab=oldest#tab-top is similar but I could not manage to add the script

Comment: Update a field is nothing more than running the field calculate tool on your table with the selection. Simply attach it to your model.